# JavaScript Ternary for function names?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ternary

I’ve come across the situation multiple times that I call a function based on a binary situation where ternary would work fine:

```
buttonPressed ? files.audio.current.play() : files.audio.current.stop()
```

But see all that extra wasted code? Is there a way instead to do something more like:

```
files.audio.current.(buttonPressed ? play : stop)()
```

Comment: This might appear "wasted code", but is actually way more readable than brackets or similar tricks. KISS!

Comment: @georg - readability and KISS are subjective. I find WET less readable.

Comment: @OriDrori: besides looking horrible, you get zero support from your IDE for this type of code (think validation, autocompletion etc)

Comment: I agree that the IDE auto completion/validation are major drawbacks. And It should require a unit test anyway to offset the possibility of runtime errors .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the brackets notation, and return the function name as a string from the trinary:

```
files.audio.current[buttonPressed ? 'play' : 'stop']()
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding a little on Ori Drori's answer:

In JavaScript functions are equivalent to fields on an object.

Therefore in a js object like so:

```
var person = {
    name: "Steve",
    sayHello: function() {
        alert("Hello!");
    }
}
```

both `person.name` and `person['name']` are valid ways of referencing the name field.

So, the `sayHello` method can be called by either `person.sayHello()` or `person['sayHello']()`

To solidify  your understanding, try `person['sayHello']` and look at what is returned!

Hope that helps!